# Loops inside of loops/Replace can't make them work

Tags: java, for-loop, replace

I want to delete all the vowels from every word inside of an array. So I came up with this:

```
public class AnotherExercise {

public static void main (String[] args){

    String[] intruments = {"cello", "guitar", "violin", "double bass"}; //the array of words
    String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}; // the array of vowels
    String[] intruments2 = new String[5]; //the array of wrods without vowels
    String nothing = ""; // used to replace a vowel to nothing

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){  // first for loop to go through all of the intruments

        for(int e = 0; e < 5; e++){ //second for loop to go through all the vowels

        intruments2[i] = intruments[i].replaceAll(vowels[e], nothing); //replacing vowels
        //and storing them in a new array
        }

        System.out.println(intruments2[i]); //outputting the words without vowels
    }

}

}
```

From all the options I tried, I guess this one was the best, but still I can't make it work, it outputs:

```
    cello
    gitar
    violin
    doble bass
```

The weirdest part in my opinion is that it does replace "u". It may be a silly mistake but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. Instead of doing one search per vowel per word why not iterate over the letters manually, testing them against the vowels. Or use one regex replace to delete all vowels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method String.[ReplaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) receives regex as first argument. It allows you to remove all vowels in one shot:

```
    public class AnotherExercise {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String[] intruments = {"cello", "guitar", "violin", "double bass"};
        String[] intruments2 = new String[5];
        String nothing = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

            intruments2[i] = intruments[i].replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u", nothing);

            System.out.println(intruments2[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

---

And, yes, about the problem with your version. In the inner loop you always apply replacement to **initial** version of the string. So you get results only from the last attempt ‒ letter 'u'.